# Multiple forms of the same entity

Tags: php, forms, symfony, symfony4, symfony-forms

I'm struggling to validate a form of a page that contains three different forms of the same entity.

I have this on my **formType** the "usuario" field is a select on my html where returns only what I filter with the "dpto" options:

```
<?php

namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\Responsavel;
use App\Entity\Usuario;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\HiddenType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class ResponsavelType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('competenciaInicial')
            ->add('cliente')
            ->add('usuario', EntityType::class, [
                'required'=> false,
                'placeholder'=> '',
                'class'=> Usuario::class,
                'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) use ($options){
                return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')
                ->where('u.ativo = 1 AND u.acesso < 9 AND u.departamento = :dpto')
                ->setParameter('dpto',$options['dpto'])
                ->orderBy('u.nome', 'ASC');}
            ])
            ->add('ativo')
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Responsavel::class,
            'dpto' => '',
        ]);
    }
    
}
```

Here's my **controller** (the same as when the page is loaded) where I created form1, form2, form3 and passed different "dpto" as option to create the view and then I did a simple test to when the form is submitted it'll dump which form it came from.

```
/**
 * @Route("/responsavel", name="responsavel_index")
 */
public function index(Request $request)
{

    $responsavel = new Responsavel();
    $contabil = $request->request->get('contabil');
    
    $form1 =  $this->createForm(ResponsavelType::class, $responsavel, ['dpto'=>'C']);
    $form1->remove('ativo');
    $form1->remove('cliente');
    $form1->remove('competenciaInicial');
    $form1->handleRequest($request);
    
    $form2 =  $this->createForm(ResponsavelType::class, $responsavel, ['dpto'=>'D']);
    $form2->remove('ativo');
    $form2->remove('cliente');
    $form2->remove('competenciaInicial');
    $form2->handleRequest($request);

    $form3 =  $this->createForm(ResponsavelType::class, $responsavel, ['dpto'=>'F']);
    $form3->remove('ativo');
    $form3->remove('cliente');
    $form3->remove('competenciaInicial');
    $form3->handleRequest($request);
    
    if ($form1->isSubmitted()) {
        dump('form1');
    }

    if($form2->isSubmitted()){
        dump('form2');
    }
    
    if($form3->isSubmitted()){
        dump('form3');
    }

    return $this->render('responsavel/index.html.twig', [
        'entity' => [],
        'form1' => $form1->createView(),
        'form2' => $form2->createView(),
        'form3' => $form3->createView()
    ]);
}
```

And here's the rendering of the forms and the js of the form submission:

```
<div class="modal-body px-4">
  <div id="clienteId" data-cliente="" class="d-none">
  </div>
  {% if app.user.acesso in [1,2,3,4,7]%}
    {% if app.user.acesso <= 3 or app.user.departamento == 'C' %}
      {{ form_start(form1, {'name' : 'responsavelContabil'})}}
        <label class="text-monospace"> Contabilidade </label>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="mb-3 col-10">
              {{form_widget(form1.usuario, {'id' : 'usuarioContabil'})}}
          </div>
          <div class="col-2 mb-3">
              <button id="okContabil" type="submit" class="btn btn-success"><i class="mdi mdi-check"></i></button>
          </div>
        </div>
      {{ form_end(form1)}}
    {% endif %}
    {% if app.user.acesso <= 3 or app.user.departamento == 'D' %}
      {{ form_start(form2, {'name' : 'responsavelDp'})}}
        <label class="text-monospace"> Dpto. Pessoal </label>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="mb-3 col-10">
              {{form_widget(form2.usuario, {'id' : 'usuarioDp'})}}
          </div>
          <div class="col-2 mb-3">
              <button id="okDp" class="btn btn-success"><i class="mdi mdi-check"></i></button>
          </div>
        </div>
      {{ form_end(form2)}}
    {% endif %}
    {% if app.user.acesso <= 3 or app.user.departamento == 'F' %}
      {{ form_start(form3, {'name' : 'responsavelFiscal'})}}
        <label class="text-monospace"> Fiscal </label>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="mb-3 col-10">
              {{form_widget(form3.usuario, {'id' : 'usuarioFiscal'})}}
          </div>
          <div class="col-2 mb-3">
              <button id="okFiscal" class="btn btn-success"><i class="mdi mdi-check"></i></button>
          </div>
        </div>
      {{ form_end(form3)}}
    {% endif %}
  {% endif %}
</div>
...

$('form').submit(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log($(this));
  var dpto = $(this[0]).attr('id').replace('usuario', '').charAt(0);

  var responsavel = {dpto:dpto, cliente: $('#clienteId').data('cliente'), responsavel: {usuario: $(this[0]).val()}}
  $.ajax({
    url: "{{ path('responsavel_index')}}",
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: responsavel,
    success: function(){
      console.log('foi');
    }
  });
```

Apparently the problem is that when I submit the form it doesn't discern one from another and then iterates all the conditions also only checks the "usuario" id passed on the request against the list of choices of the form created on form1 and then returns a "field is not valid" error of the passed "usuario" id on form validator.

Any ideas of what I'm doing wrong and how to fix it or how to debug it?

Thanks ind Advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try to distinguis the forms via their names, the keys that passes through the request.

```
public function __construct() {
    $this->prefix = self::$count++;
}

private $prefix;
private static $count = 0;

public function getBlockPrefix() {
    return $this->prefix . '_form';
}
```

This was a code for your form type. With that, the rendered inputs will have different names for each form, like:

```
    <input type="text" id="form_name" name="0_form[name]" class="form-control">
```

Every form will have different suffix and their submitted values will not interfere with others. Just be sure you create the forms in the same order while rendering and processing the submitted form later, as the suffix is dependent on the order (the "count++" part). Try it and let me know if that works.

UPDATE:

This will not work in symfony 3+. The instance is created only once, but the method buildForm in yout Type is called every time you initiate form in Controller guaranteedy. So:

```
private $formPrefix;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->formPrefix = 0;
}
public function getBlockPrefix()
{
    return $this->formPrefix . '-' . parent::getBlockPrefix();
}

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
    ++$this->formPrefix;
    ...
}
```

> Blockquote

[The result of creating 2 forms](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d8kWf.png)

Comment: And also, the '_form' part of getBlockPrefix is just like 'foo', replace it with whatever you want. The $count variable also can be used as sufix ofc.

Comment: Thanks for the help! And how will my controller look like? I've pasted the _construct and getBlocPrefix on my formType it changed the names of the rendered form elements but on all three the prefix is "0_form"

Comment: Oh I see why this does not work in Symfony 3+, the instance is created only once. I will update my answer. Tried this method and it works

Comment: It didn't work, still repeats the 0 as prefix

Comment: Sry I did not mention the ++ in buildForm @LucasMarques .The buildForm function is added into the answer